issues with ubuntu 24.04 lte on old gigabyte motherboard
I have a ga-b85m-d3h motherboard with 24 GB RAM and i7 CPU.
So far used Win10, bought a 1TB SSD, and decided to give ubuntu a try...
Installed Ubuntu 24.04 LTE desktop on the SSD and facing several issues:

the wifi stops working after awhile -- had to turn-off its power saving feature
after resuming from standby, the mouse cursor appears as a white box together with other icons, cannot log-in, cannot restart, only cold power-off works :(
cannot get my HP DeskJet 2700 printer to work :(
cannot get docker desktop to work :(
sometimes, mysteriosly, Google Chrome crashes repeatedly

all of the above works fine with my Win10 on same machine.
Several years ago, when this machine was new, tried ubuntu, maybe 16, and it almost worked fine except youtube and all other kinds of videos. Tried drivers, configurations for about 2 weeks... then installed Win10. Why does it always suc*s?...
BR,
Adrian.

24.04 is a new release, and it may take a while to filter out the bugs (a lots of users are encountering bugs, judging from the questions in this site). You can stay at 22.04 instead (supported until 2027)

This is a question & answer site. Or each of your 5 questions should be one question, so you get one answer. If you want you can also try Ubuntu Forums which offers better back & forth answers on more complex issues.

Yesterday I decided to install 22.04.4 LTS. At the beginning it looked promising. It woke up from suspend correctly and there where no wifi diconnections. Now, after leaving it on for a awhile, it suspended automatically and when woke up the SSD looks like no longer available. All bash commands return "input/output error" and almost no icons appeared on the screen. Only a cold restart was possible. Any suggestions?

gave up and installed windows 10... now dicovered the same behavior -- seems like and ssd/bios related issue
